# Get class instance and override methods

Tags: java, android

I want to override the ListenerClass overriden methods in the `doInBackground()` method of a different class in order for the location changes to be tracked in a separate thread.

I have the ListenerClass

```
public class ListenerClass implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

}
```

And i instantiate it here in order to be able to `requestLocationUpdates()` since it mustn't be null in order to call that method.

```
class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private Criteria criteria;
    private TextView textView;
    private ListenerClass listenerClass;

    public AsyncClass(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        listenerClass = new ListenerClass();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 10, listenerClass);
    }
```

And lastly, i want to override the methods of the location listener in the separate thread.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Looper.prepare();
        listenerClass.getClass();//What shall i do here?

        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: not clear - I want to override the ListenerClass overriden methods in the doInBackground() method of a different class

Comment: @SanjayKumar I have a class ListenerClass that implements the LocationListener and its methods. I want to again override these methods in the doInBackground method of the Async task. How do i call the instance of the ListenerClass such that the methods are implemented in the doInBackgorund method?

Comment: Do you want run inside of onLocationChanged method on different thread ?

Comment: @Blackkara exactly. In the doInBackground basically

Comment: Could you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve? I.e. what would the purpose of this be?

Comment: `requestLocationUpdates` makes possible to run `onLocationChanged` method on different thread. Hope [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) helps you

Comment: @Michael I want the location updates to happen in a seaprate thread. That is basically it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override, but you need to create new instance.

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Looper.prepare();
        listenerClass = new LocationListener() {
        // Other overrided methods....
          @Override
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

          }

          }

        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this and it says error incompatible types, since the LocationListener is a different class than the one i have created.

Comment: What is the issue? Change reference to the supertype.

Comment: So, in the initialisation have LocationListener listenerClass = new ListenerClass()?  I've tried this and then did as you have shown in your answer but still the onLocationChanged is not overwriten.

Answer (score 0):

you can override any method of listener class but you will not receive location update because this new instance is not registered with location manager

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Looper.prepare();
            ....
              new ListenerClass(){
                @Override
                public boolean onProviderEnabled(Location location) {
                  ....
                }
            };

            .....

        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: But can't i override the instance of ListenerClass in the doInBackground method? Isn't it still the same one registered for the requestLocationUpdates()?

Comment: which method do you want to override ?

Comment: onLocationChanged

Comment: do you receive some location in do in background?. Why you need to call this method in do in background

Comment: Because i want the location updates to happen in a separate thread

Comment: Location update already happened in separate thread. You just receive it in Main Thread